# how do I enforce https connections for main domain while also enforcing http for subdomains?

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, wildcard, multisite, wildcard-subdomain

In the context of Wordpress Multisite installation I need to enforce https connection for the main domain (let's call it https://site.lt) while at the same time enforcing insecure connection for subdomains (http://en.site.lt, http://ru.site.lt). I need to do that on the shared hosting, by configuring .htaccess file. The problem is, the hosting provider installs Let's Encrypt sertificate only for the domain and for the configured subdomains, but without wildcard support, but Wordpress Multisite uses virtual subdomains (no en/ or ru/ directories to correspond to the subdomain name). So I need to use the ssl where I can but avoid insecure connection warnings on the subdomains.

Here is what I have now ("MY CODE HERE" marks where I am deviating from WP defaults):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

## MY CODE HERE:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ru.site.lt$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en.site.lt$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^en.site.lt$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^ru.site.lt$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
## END MY CODE

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

It does enforce https on the main domain, but it works in only limited way for the subdomains. If I try to open https://en.site.lt, first of all I get a warning screen that the connection is not safe, and only once I accept the unsafe connection (make an exception) does the rewrite rule kick in and I get redirected to http site... Which is quite pointless by the time the user has accepted the unsafe connection.

Comment: Do your subdomains work on `https` ?

Comment: Well, only if you add a security exception. The browser complains of certificate mismatch. And that's poor UX.

Comment: I have updated my question with my current rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0):

For an SSL/TSL certificate to cover both domain and subdomains, it must be a Wildcard certificate. A Wildcard certificate is a digital certificate that is applied to a domain and all its subdomains.

> *...A conventional SSL certificate works on a single domain, for example
> domain.com. A wildcard certificate for *.domain.com will also
> protect mail.domain.com, vpn.domain.com, payment.domain.com, etc...*

*Learn more about Wildcards certificates @ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate*.
*Source @ https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/wildcard-certificate*

> *...It does enforce https on the main domain, but it works in only limited way for the subdomains...*

Upon subscribing to a certificate, the certificate is delivered for any currently living domain and subdomains. If your subdomains were create AFTER you subscribed to a certificate, you need to ask for a new one. Usually the process is free and can be done from your hosting provider website.

**Most of the time you don't need to even touch your `.htaccess` regarding SSL/TSL certificate.**
The only thing you want to ensure is that any http request is redirected to the https one: `RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

Comment: The problem is that my subdomains are not defined in the server itself (which involves both creating a folder in the filesystem under public_html and some configuration rule in the hosting config). Therefore the server cannot know anything about them, and cannot request a certificate covering the subdomains. It barely allows for wildcard subdomains in configuration, but the subdomains themselves are provided by the Wordpress Multisite installation. And for some reasong the hosting provider does not offer wildcard Let's Encrypt certs (I mean sertificates that would cover any subdomain name)...